# Cocoa App: Discovering what apps can deal with images and videos

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to discover what apps can deal with images and videos and I pretend to launch the default app for the type, from my app after that.

I have this code:

```
    CFArrayRef *array = LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType(kUTTypeAudiovisualContent, kLSRolesEditor);
```

after running this `array = NULL`

I was expecting to see Photoshop, Preview, etc., on that list but I got it null.

NOTE: This is a sandboxed app that will be distributed on the App Store. Is this why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That call would only return applications which claimed they could handle the entirely generic and abstract "audiovisual content" type. Almost no app is going to claim that. How could they? What app could conceivably handle every single variant of audiovisual content?

For example, if you're writing an app that handles images, surely there's only some specific types of images that you can handle (`public.png`, `public.jpeg`, `public.tiff`, etc.). You can't claim to handle images completely generally (i.e. `public.image`). That would mean that you're claiming to handle images in every conceivable file format, even formats not invented yet, since, once they are invented, their UTI will surely conform to `public.image`.

For the same reason, no app can claim to handle `public.audiovisual-​content`.

(By the way, `public.image` doesn't conform to `public.audiovisual-​content`. So the latter doesn't encompass "images and videos".)

You're going to have to search for some more specific UTIs that apps are actually likely to claim to handle. I don't know if sandboxing will interfere with this task beyond that. You can build a non-sandboxed version of your app to test.

I'm not sure what you mean by "I pretend to launch the default app for the type". What does it mean to "pretend" to launch an app?

Comment: That's it. Thanks. By "pretend" I mean "will". In other words, once I discover what apps can deal with with the Type I will launch one with the content. THANKS

Comment: One strange thing: I run this `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType(kUTTypeJPEG, kLSRolesEditor)` and got back 3 objects: imageOptim, ColorSyncUtility and Preview. Photoshop is not on the list, what is strange. When I right click on a JPEG image and click open with I see 15 options, including illustrator, Photoshop, Safari and others.

Comment: Take a look at the Info.plist file within one of the apps which you think ought to handle a given type but doesn't. Also, look at the output of `mdls` when applied to the image file. One possibility: an app doesn't use the modern technique of declaring what types it handles by UTI but instead uses file extensions. Another: the file is actually of some more-specific type and the app claims that but not `image.jpeg`. Generally, if you have a file in mind for what your code wants to do, you can try `LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL()` or `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()`.